# The term 'New-CsOnlineSession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to run a power shell script from the c#.
When running the power shell script only, it runs successfully. But , while trying to run the same script from the c# . I get the error "The term 'New-CsOnlineSession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Here is the code:

```
          public static void GetLyncUsers(string userName, string password)
        {
            using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {

                var script = string.Format("$Username =\"{0}\"\n" +
                                           "$Password =\"{1}\"\n" +
                                           "$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force\n" +
                                           "$cred = new-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username  , $secpasswd)\n" +
                                           "$CSSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $cred\n" +
                                           "Import-PSSession $CSSession -AllowClobber\n" +
                                           "Get-CsOnlineUser", userName, password);

                // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
                // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.

                powerShellInstance.AddScript(script);


                // use "AddParameter" to add a single parameter to the last command/script on the pipeline.


                // invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
                Collection<PSObject> psOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke();

                // check the other output streams (for example, the error stream)
                if (powerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                {
                    // I am getting this error 
                  //The term 'New-CsOnlineSession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
                }
        }
```

Is there anything i am missing? I am new to powershell in general.

Comment: Have you tried importing the lync module manually into that session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{    
    // Import-Module lynconlineconnector
    powershellInstance.Commands
        .AddCommand("Import-Module")
        .AddArgument("lynconlineconnector");

// rest of your code ....
```

**Why?**

When running an interactive session in powershell v3 and higher, the host traps CommandNotFound, and searches every module in all the known locations. If it finds the command, it automatically loads the module, and proceeds normally.

When running same script in C#, the CommandNotFound exception isn't trapped, and hence you get the error.

**Related Question(s):**

[PowerShell - How to Import-Module in a Runspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266108/powershell-how-to-import-module-in-a-runspace)

[#PSTip Cmdlet Discovery and Module auto-loading](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/09/27/cmdlet-discovery-and-module-auto-loading/)

Comment: Does not work. {The specified module 'lynconlineconnector' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.}

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. You have to install the Lync/Skype For Business Online Connector as described on [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn362829(v=ocs.15).aspx)

> The setup program copies the Skype for Business Online Connector
>   module (and the New-CsOnlineSession cmdlet) to your local computer.