# C# Powershell executing custom function from script file

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a powershell script file that contains multiple functions. I would like to call one of the functions using C#. When I invoke my command, it throws an error

```
    "The term 'LogIn-System' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
```

Here is some sample code:

```
using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
   powerShellInstance.Runspace = runSpace;

   powerShellInstance
     .AddScript("myfunctions.ps1")
     .Invoke();
   powerShellInstance
     .AddCommand("LogIn-System")
     .AddParameter("SystemName", "Connect");
   Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = await Task.Run(() => 
     powerShellInstance.Invoke());
}
```

Comment: `AddScript()` should be commands instead of a path. Try either dot-sourcing with `.AddScript(".\myfunctions.ps1")` or use `Import-Module` like  `.AddScript("Import-Module myfunctions.ps1")` instead. Or check out one of the other suggestions in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266108/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two separate invokes. One to import the module, the second is your script. Since Import-Module is a Command from a previous loaded module, call it with AddCommand. Specify the Module name to import with the AddParameter function. For example:

```
PS
   .AddCommand("Import-Module")
   .AddParameter("Name", "ExchangeOnlineManagement")
   .Invoke();

PS
   .AddScript([your script name])
   .Invoke();
```